# Azure DevOps Release pipeline using build tags

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I'm trying to understand how the option Build tags works inside the Continuous deployment trigger of the release pipeline.

[build tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY2uz.png)

Here I can add Build tags, in my build pipeline is set the following build tags: `$(Build.DefinitionName)_$(Build.BuildNumber)` But when I put the same inside the build tags at the Release pipeline. It won't do anything.

The tag's are succesfully added: [tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGbhm.png)

What I'm trying to archive is that when a build is successful a tag is created and the release pipline is triggered when the tag is the same as the one I set after the build.

Is this how it should work, or do I mix thing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doing an exact name match of the build tag.  If you wanted this to work, you'd need to put the hard-coded build number.  Not the template for creating the build number.

For my product, we build in both debug and release configurations.  I will stamp a tag either { debug, release}.  Then on the release pipeline, you might have the build tag only flagged for { release }, so you don't ever deploy debug copies.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this clears up my mind. Going to try what you are suggesting :)

So: first I add a tag at my build pipeline like: "customer_$(Build.BuildNumber)"
At my release pipeline I set the Continuous deployment trigger build branch to: "refs/tags/customer*" and it should work, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, I think if you want the release to trigger specifically from a branch build being completed, the CD triggers are the way to go.